# Facebook Messenger link/redirect

Tags: facebook, messenger

On a real estate search page with multiple agencies and agents listing their properties I want the user to have the possibility to contact the agents via Fb Messenger.
So form one page he could start moultiple and different messenger conversations. Does Facebook allow it?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a different 'send to messenger' for each: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger